# Receive Location Files are picked up but not removed

Tags: biztalk

I have a receive Location which points to SFTP Port, the Files in the ports are picked up and sent to the destination(Send Port). But the files which are picked up still exists in the receive location and doesn't gets removed. So every time the receive location trying to pick up the same file which throws error. How can I deal with this.

Comment: Have you verified the logon user has delete permissions?

Comment: @Johns How to verify that.When I check in FileZilla, the Folder has drwxrwxrwx permission, and the files has -rw-rw-rw- permission.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on the SFTP receive location, where you can specify to delete the file after it has been received.

[image]

Comment: Is that the bLogical SFTP adapter?  As the standard BizTalk SFTP adapter does not have those options and does not look like the screenshot above.